# executables and the path variable

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, environment-variables

When working in any command shell, one usually has to type in the specific path in order to run an executable program. Like for example

```
start c:/ProgramFiles/Steam.exe
```

I know that's not the real directory for steam but whatever.

However, there are executables that I didn't have to type a whole directory for like `chrome.exe`. All I had to do was type start `chrome.exe` in my shell and boom, there pops a window. I am simply wondering why this is the case, if chrome is "special" in any case.

a possible explanation i have is when running an executable, the the shell usually looks within the current working directory and sees if the executable exists. If not, it searches in the environment variables and looks at a variable called the `PATH` variable. Since the path variable is a bunch of random paths mashed together in one line, it searches every path for an executable that matches the run call. However, when I looked through my `PATH` variable, I got this:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
```

I did not find a path in there that points to the location of `chrome.exe` which would be `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application`
can someone please explain what is this `PATH` variable actually used for?

I know by the generic definition it's used when programs need to know where to install something, start something, etc, but there are only like 5 paths in there and I have hundreds of programs installed so I don't see how that would work and why `chrome.exe` is behaving this way?

Comment: I might have tried to answer this and find your question well designed, but reading it a 2nd time, I think it could be off topic and better fit on SuperUser. That's only my thought. Let's see what others say to that.

Answer (score 0):

The most of your thoughts to the `%PATH%` variable are correct. However, consider that there are *System environment variables* and *User environment variables*.

Paths in the `PATH` variable are not *random* like you say. They all serve a purpose. Most of them are added during a software installation, allowing you or the system to easily find executables, which is not as easy as it might sound. E.g. you have a programs folder for 32bit apps, and one for 64bit apps. There is the `%windir%/System32` folder, your user folder and some manual installations.

Also, the operating system does not only search for `.exe` executables. `.bat` files, for example are also executed by the default command prompt (`cmd`), PowerShell on the other hand has a so-called profile, which remembers a bit of the `.bashrc` and can define *Aliases* and *functions*, one might know from the bash-world.

To find out why `chrome.exe` is executed, type the following in your PowerShell:

```
Get-Command chrome.exe
```

And it will show you, what *defines* that command. Is it an exe file? Yes, it is.

Comment: I typed in get-command chrome.exe and it says chrome.exe is not a recognized cmdlet nor command. Also since the PATH variable is used to locate executables, i have hundreds of executables yet there are only 5 paths. Why is that?

Comment: What's with `Get-Command chrome`. I wrote `chrome.exe` because, you told that that's what you are typing, but typically, I'd write just `chrome`. What I mean: you can't execute chrome with `chrome.exe` w/o PowerShell able to resolve it.

Comment: I'd guess there are not just 5 paths. However, at least in `system32` are _hundreds_ of executables.